# React - pass props into input component

Tags: reactjs

What I need is to be able to customize `textAreaCount` and other props in each separate instance of `<Texarea/>`. The `textAreaCount` is different for each `<Texarea/>` so how do I modify the component to be able to pass in custom `textAreaCount` for each `<Texarea/>`?

https://codesandbox.io/s/rkv88-forked-vjo0rn?file=/src/App.js:0-948

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Textarea = (value, id, maxLength, textAreaLimit) => {

  const [textAreaCount, ChangeTextAreaCount] = React.useState(0);

  const [state, setstate] = useState({
    headline: "",
    title: ""
  });

  const { headline, title } = state;

  const changevalue = (e) => {
    setstate({
      ...state,
      [e.target.name]: value
    });
    ChangeTextAreaCount(e.target.value.length);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <p>{textAreaCount}/{textAreaLimit}</p>
      <textarea
        type="text"
        rows={5}
        id={id}
        value={value}
        maxLength={maxLength}
        onChange={(e) => {
          changevalue(e);
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default function FullWidthTabs() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Textarea value={headline} id="test" maxLength={5} textAreaLimit={5}/>

      <Textarea value={title} id="test2" maxLength={10} textAreaLimit={10}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: you want to write a reusable input component. but you want to use for both, input and textarea. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Forward the props you need.

```js
const Textarea = (props) => {
  const [textAreaCount, setTextAreaCount] = React.useState(0);

  const recalculate = (e) => {
    setTextAreaCount(e.target.value.length);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <p>{textAreaCount}/5</p>
      <textarea type="text" rows={5} maxLength={5} onChange={recalculate} {...props} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Now it will forward any props into the textarea element. This will set the `id` and will overwrite the `rows` prop.

```js
<Textarea id="textarea-1" rows={4} />
<Textarea id="textarea-2" rows={5} maxLength={10} />
```

Comment: Updated question for more clarity

Answer (score 0):

As we can see you try to pass props as below:

```
<Textarea value={title} id="test2" maxLength={10} textAreaLimit={10}/>
```

But In Your Textarea Component you received props argument as multiple args as below:

```
const Textarea = (value, id, maxLength, textAreaLimit) => {
  return (
    <>
    </>
  );
};
```

Instead that you need to destruct your props argument or you can set whole passed value props as single object props as below:

Method 1:

```
const Textarea = ({value, id, maxLength, textAreaLimit}) => {
   return (
      <>
         <textarea type="text" id={id} value={value} rows={5} maxLength={maxLength} onChange={recalculate} textAreaLimit={textAreaLimit}  />
      </>
   );
};
```

Method 2:

```
const Textarea = ({...props}) => {
   return (
      <>
         <textarea type="text" id={id} value={value} rows={5} maxLength={maxLength} onChange={recalculate} textAreaLimit={textAreaLimit}  />
      </>
   );
};
```

Method 3:

```
const Textarea = (props) => {
   return (
      <>
         <textarea type="text" id={props.id} value={props.value} rows={5} maxLength={props.maxLength} onChange={recalculate} textAreaLimit={props.textAreaLimit}  /> 
        // Or Instead you can do as below
        // <textarea type="text" rows={5} maxLength={5} onChange={recalculate} {...props} />
      </>
   );
};
```

Comment: What I need is to be able to customize `textAreaCount` and other props in each separate instance of `<Texarea/>` The `textAreaCount` is different for each `<Texarea/>` so how do I modify the component to be able to pass in custom `textAreaCount` for each `<Texarea/>`?